# TypeScript cannot return object with same base as generic parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a factory that returns config values based on Entities that extend the BaseEntity.  However, I get a type error saying that a type with the same signature as the generic parameter cannot be returned from the function, specifically Type `Collection<A> is not assignable to type Collection<T>` and that `Type A is not assignable to type T`.  However, don't `A` and `T` have the same definitions in this example?

```
type BaseTypes = 'a';

interface Base {
  type: BaseTypes;
  id: number;
}

interface A extends Base {
  type: 'a';
  name: string;
}

interface Collection<T extends Base> {
  items: T[];
}

function getCollection<T extends Base>(obj: T): Collection<T> | null {
  switch (obj.type) {
    case 'a':
      return getACollection(); // Type Collection<A> is not assignable to type Collection<T>
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

function getACollection(): Collection<A> {
  return { items: [] };
}
```

Comment: Right... that shouldn't work. Much for the same reason as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301).

Comment: @JeffMercado how is that the same though? This isn't a list of "Animal" it is a list of classes extending Animal.  What I am trying to do is `doSomething(List<? extends Animal> animals` but it is giving a type error.

Comment: Sorry, not the best reason. But look at it this way, `T` is some type that extends `Base`. `A` is a specific type that extended `Base`. There's no guarantees that `T` is `A`. Since the return type is `Collection<T>`, `Collection<A>` cannot satisfy that type.

Comment: @JeffMercado interesting, I was expecting that the string literal would act as a type guard.

Comment: In this context, I don't think that would matter. That check only constrains what `obj` can be, not necessarily what `T` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript needs a union type for type guards to work, `Base` is the base type for your derived interfaces but is not a union so there is no union for the compiler to narrow.

The second problem is that Typescript will not narrow a generic type even if it were to extend a union (although I belive this will change in a future release, I'll post the github issue if I find it. **Edit** [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) is the issue but apparently there are no plans to implement it). But even if it were to narrow the type of the parameter, it would only have narrowed the parameter, type guards would not impact the return type of the function. Type guards are very narrow in what they impact.

The simplest solution to your problem is to have two different signatures for the function, a public one with a generic parameter and a private one without generics that takes `Base` and returns a `Collection<Base>`. This is not a fully type safe solution, as the implementation could take in one derivation of `Base` and return collectionsl of a different derivation, but it's the best we can do right now.

```
function getCollection<T extends Base>(obj: T): Collection<T> | null
function getCollection(obj: Base): Collection<Base> | null {
    switch (obj.type) {
        case 'a':
            return getACollection(); 
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```